# Which way blows Zephyrus?

Tags: greek

This is more like a technical, geographical question.

When we say Zephyrus is the west wind, do we mean *coming from* the west or *going* west?

Which way would my boat go if Zephyrus blew into the sails?

(I thought here would be a better place to ask rather than a geography forum)

Answer (score 3):

From the west.

Note that Boreaus, the North Wind, brought cold winter air from the north.